# Validate string value in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, validation

I'm playing with Python. I try to validate a variable value. Should be super simple but I'm struggling. Here are the req's:

1. Value must have exactly 3 char = +49
2. Value must have exactly the format = +49

I tried to loop through the string variable. I used a for loop. I also tried to save the values in an array and check the array later on.

```
def validateCountryCode(self):
        val = ["1", "2", "3"]
        i = 0
        for val[i] in self.countryCode
            print(val[i])
            val[i] += 1
```

I would now start to check the array with an if-statement but I don't get to the point because it seems that I already went the wrong way.

Comment: What is the input and what is the expected output? i didnt get the req's

Comment: You don't increase your i value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the most simple validator I could imagine:

```
def validateCountryCode(countrycode):

  # Check if countrycode is exact 3 long
  if len(countrycode) != 3:
    return False

  # CHECK FORMAT
  # Check if it starts with +
  if countrycode[0] != "+":
    return False

  # Check second and third character is int
  try: 
      int(countrycode[1])
      int(countrycode[2])
  except ValueError:
      return False


  # All checks passed!
  return True


# True
print(validateCountryCode("+32"))

# False
print(validateCountryCode("332"))

# False
print(validateCountryCode("+2n"))
```

Comment: hi all - first of all many thanks for answering. @Wimanicesir, this could be the keyanswer. I will paly around with that.

by the way - someone marked the question as "duplicate". What do I have to do? I couldn't find a answer to the question before.

Comment: Many thanks - I think I can work with the information. but currently I'm getting the following error:

    if not isinstance(int(x[2]), int):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'n'

I'v entered the Value "+2n" for testing purpose. 
n is a char and I would expect "return false" instead of the error message.

Comment: No problem! About the problem, I will edit. Just a second. :)

Comment: Hey Mr. Sun, I added some error handling so it won't crash on non integer input. I don't know if you have the power to unlift the duplicate marking.

Comment: Wow - that blew me away! It works... many many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this simple expression might work OK:

```
^[+][0-9]{2}$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GakGEL/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

expression = r'^[+][0-9]{2}$'
string = '''
+00
+49
+99
+100
'''

matches = re.findall(expression, string, re.M)

print(matches)
```

#### Output

```
['+00', '+49', '+99']
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/GakGEL/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/GakGEL/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: wow, Emma!!! 
Many thanks, bookmarked it!